# About creating a random key under Uid in firebase realtime database using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a simple app using android studio and firebase realtime database. When a user registered his data, it will be saved under Uid that firebase provides.
Then i have created another node inside Uid called "PATH" and i want to store some data that user provides inside that. To do that i want to create specific id or something so that it won't be replaced every time that user enters a new data. (Check the screenshot)

[image: This is what i want to do]

I have tried to do this by using Datasnapshot but it doesn't respond to the click. This is what i tried.

```
add_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if( !Validate_text() ){
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picker.getDayOfMonth() + "-" + picker.getMonth() + "-" + picker.getYear(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // redirect to path

                    String ach = milestone.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                    int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
                    int month = picker.getMonth();
                    int year = picker.getYear();
                    String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year ;

                    reference.child(uid).child("PATH").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            for( DataSnapshot random_key : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                                String key = random_key.getKey();
                                Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                updates.put("Achievement : ", ach);
                                updates.put("Date", date);
                                reference.child(uid).child("PATH").child(key).updateChildren(updates).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your achievement has been updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(AddPath.this, Path.class));
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Log.v(TAG, error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

If anyone have idea what i have done wrong here or can help, you are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer that you construct your database json something like this.

```
-users
   -userUid
      -name: "Ticherhaz"
      -others: "Master"
   -userUid2
      -name: "Pyke"
      -others: "Bronze"
-path
   -userUid
      -pathUid
         -achievement: "Eat without using hand"
         -date: "12/02/2022"
      -pathUid2
         -achievement: "Wake up early"
         -date: "12/02/2022"
   -userUid2
      -pathUid3
         -achievement: "Feeding team"
         -date: "13/02/2022"
```

Since you say you want to create random Uid, you can use Firebase `pushId`. You can refer here, [Firebase Push ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#push-vs-transaction).

```
    add_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if( !Validate_text() ){
                return;
            }
            else{
                String ach = milestone.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
                int day = picker.getDayOfMonth();
                int month = picker.getMonth();
                int year = picker.getYear();
                String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year ;

                Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                updates.put("Achievement : ", ach);
                updates.put("Date", date);

                final String pushId = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().getKey(); //Create new random Id
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("path").child(uid).child(pushId).setValue(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your achievement has been updated.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(AddPath.this, Path.class));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much @TicherhazFreePalastine . Your solution worked. I have rearranged the structure as you mentioned as well. Thank you again..